# Woocommerce Absolute discount for specific simple products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

First of all, I have several simple products in my Woocommerce shop.
If a customer takes 2 pieces of one product, the price should not double. Instead Product A costs 40 for 1 piece and if the customer wants a second piece it should cost 20 - so overall 60. Product B - 1 unit costs 25 and 2 units should costs 40 in total for example.

I have tried to add an absolute value to the cart total, but even this does not work (found this code on stackoverflow).

```
  function add_discount_price_absolute( $cart_object ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $custom_discount_absolute = 15; // custom discount percent
    $pdtcnt=0;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $pdtcnt++;
        if($pdtcnt>1) { // from second product
            $oldprice = $cart_item['data']->price; //original product price
            $newprice = $oldprice + $custom_discount_absolute; //discounted price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($newprice);
        }        
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_discount_price_absolute' );
```

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks